# Set height for select in vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

Is it possible to set v-select height using vuetify API?
I know it is possible, but for large height.
[image]

If i set height:100 i will see that it works.
But if the value is too low, it won't work.

I noticed that if the textfield is box or outline min-height of 56px is set:

```
.v-text-field--box .v-input__slot, .v-text-field--outline .v-input__slot { min-height: 56px; }
```

And for solo text fields, the min-height is 48px:

```
.v-text-field.v-text-field--solo .v-input__control { min-height: 48px; }
```

Is setting height using css the only option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Until now I think is the best option. There are several input classes below `v-input`. `v-input__slot` and `.v-input__control` are the most important. The same happens with `v-button` min-height and other input components.